# Creating TFS bug in Test Manager and link to a User Story

Tags: user-stories

When creating a bug with Microsoft Test Manager (or via the Test tab in TFS web UI) I want any bugs created to appear on the product backlog underneath the corresponding user story.

Current steps:

1. Create new requirements-based suite
2. Select a user story
3. List item
4. Create a suite
5. Add a test case (this has a link to 'Tested user stories' back to #2).
6. Run the suite, observe a test failure, create a bug.
7. Bug has a link to the test case created in #4.

Is it possible for the bug to have a direct link to the user story rather than the test case? Ideally we would like to see the bug in our backlog, below the user story. As it stands that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can link bug to user story directly via following steps:

1. Click "All Links" option in the bug/story.
2. Click "Link to..." button.
3. In the displayed dialog, you can select the link type and either enter the ID for the user story/bug you want to link or click "..." to open an advanced query dialog.

Note: Select "Child" link type when you link a bug from user story or select "Parent" link type when you link a user story from bug if you want to show the bug under user story. And you can only associate bug with user story manually.

To show the bug on backlog or task board:

If you are using the TFS Version after 2013.4, you can change your TFS settings via following steps:

1. Open TFS Web UI.
2. Enter "Control Panel" page by clicking the setting icon in the up-right corner.
3. Click your team name.
4. Click "Settings" button.

Then you will see three options under "Working with bugs" section and you can choose one of them for your working.[Refer to this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ6cv.png)

If you are using the TFS Version before 2013.4, you need to customize WIT to accomplish this feature. For how to customize the WIT, please refer to this link from MSDN for details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920163%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#opt_b